# push_back to vector in c++ vs add to list in c#

Tags: c#, c++, list, vector

I have 1 code in C++ and 1 in c#

I should emphasize that I just measured time around one .push-back and one .add and for their 10000 occurrences I write the time spent. so rest of the code has no importance. I just wrote them for clarification.

the c++ code

```
void pv(int depth, m1* prevM1)
{
    if (depth == 0)
        return;
    vector <m1> *mList;
    if (prevM1->childM1 != 0)
        mList = prevMove->childM1;
    else 
    {
        mList = new vector<m1>;   
        f1 (mList);
    }
    for(vector<m1>::iterator it=mList.begin(); it !=m1.end(); ++it)
    {
         pv(depth - 1 ,it.chilM1);
    }
    prevM1->childM1 = mList;
}



void f1(vector<m1>* Moves)
{
```

//I have a counter and a time around this push_back. when it reaches 10000 times I print time

```
    m1 obj;
    Moves->push_back(obj);
```

// and Here

```
    m1 obj2;
    Moves->push_back(obj2);
    m1 obj3;
    Moves->push_back(obj3);
    m1 obj4;
    Moves->push_back(obj4);
    m1 obj5;
    Moves->push_back(obj5);
    m1 obj6;
    Moves->push_back(obj6);
    m1 obj7;
    Moves->push_back(obj7);
    m1 obj8;
    Moves->push_back(obj8);
    m1 obj9;
    Moves->push_back(obj9);
    m1 obj10;
    Moves->push_back(obj10);
}
```

--------> I execute this in main

```
m1 move;
PV(10, &Moves);
```

the c# code

```
m1 f1()
{
    List<m1> Moves = new List<m1>();
```

//I have a counter and a time around this Add. when it reaches 10000 times I print time

```
    m1 obj = new m1();
    Moves.Add(obj);
```

//and here

```
    m1 obj2 = new m1();
    Moves.Add(obj2);        
    m1 obj3 = new m1();
    Moves.Add(obj3);        
    m1 obj4 = new m1();
    Moves.Add(obj4);        
    m1 obj5 = new m1();
    Moves.Add(obj5);        
    m1 obj6 = new m1();
    Moves.Add(obj6);        
    m1 obj7 = new m1();
    Moves.Add(obj7);        
    m1 obj8 = new m1();
    Moves.Add(obj8);        
    m1 obj9 = new m1();
    Moves.Add(obj9);        
    m1 obj10 = new m1();
    Moves.Add(obj10);
    return Moves;    
}

void PV(int depth,m1 prevM1)
{
    List<m1> mList;
    if (depth == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (prevMove.childM1 != null)
    {
        mList = prevMove.childM1;
    }
    else
    {
        mList = f1();
    }
    foreach(m1 move in mList)
    {
        pv(depth - 1, move);
    }
```

--------> I execute this in main

```
m1 move;
PV(10, move);
```

and m1 class is same in both c++ and c#
in C#

```
class m1
{
    public String ms;
    public List<m1> childM1;
    public double d;
}
```

in c++

```
class m1
{
    public:
        string ms;
        m1* childM1;
        double d;
}
```

the code in c# executed in 12 milliseconds but code in c++ executed in 143 milliseconds. I run it lots of time to be sure of the difference. the code in c++ was at least 10 times slower than the code in c#. as vector in c++ is same as List in c# it seems I missed something so I found this difference.

Any help would highly welcomed.

Comment: The first one: 'vector<m1> *Moves;' will not work. Moves is not created. Further more do the testing with the creating of the vector/list outside of the loop.

Comment: @PoweRoy: As I said in my last comment the real code is a lot more complicated. I just made it brief. so the creation of the list/vector is inside the loop. anyway: the benefit is for c++ because of not creating any object in the code that I posted before.

Comment: If your real code is different, this question is useless. Post a small, selfcontained benchmark (including timing methods) and you have Jon Skeet material. My guess is, it won't be possible to show that is slower in that way.

Comment: The standard questions, did you enable optimizations? Which compiler? Are you sure you want to test code that is completely and utterly stupid (creating vectors with 1 element and then immediately destroying it). You know that C# has a faster deallocator, because it can defer deallocation to sometime in the future (note: program exit).

Comment: @sehe : the real code is not that different. just they are functions and are called from  the same for as I wrote the only difference is this. and because of that I passed moves from that function call

Comment: @Christopher : visual studio 2010. I said the real code is not that stupid. But It is a lot more complicated. I just extracted the part that had strange behavior of time

Comment: If it is that important I will write the functions call in my post again in a minute

Comment: @sehe: I posted the real code again. for sure I omitted lots of parts. But I just get time of this parts. And I used clock()

Comment: @MasoudHabibi: I cannot reproduce this result (using ideone: [C++](http://ideone.com/SLBkq) -- 0.001094 seconds, [C#](http://ideone.com/XRkBt) -- 0.0051788 seconds).

Comment: The C# compiler will probably optimize `f1` to a big `no-op`. Also, how are you timing this? I'm not convinced. You used `clock()`? That's CPU time in user code, IIRC. Also, you used that in C#?

Comment: @sehe: It seems I am really awful at summarizing my code. It is really recursive. Not a simple for to be removed.

Comment: @MasoudHabibi: Then your question reduces to, "How can I optimize my code, which I won't show you?". Profile your code using `callgrind` and `kcachegrind` and optimize whatever sticks out. (I think you must be measuring in some kind of broken way though. 143ms for that trivial code seems absurd.)

Comment: @Mankarse good stuff. Post as an anwer? Also, using `struct m1` in C# speeds it up _a little_. My guess is, MS.NET would be a hell of a lot slower (see http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/08/23/optimization-and-generics-part-2-lambda-expressions-and-reference-types.aspx)

Comment: @sehe: I'm not really sure how to answer as I can't even reproduce the problem (much less give a solution).

Comment: I will post it with a lot more complete details. i am sorry. but when I post it you will understand there is just 10000 push_back vs 10000 add. please accept me.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : I tried hard to summerize 5000 lines of code to 30 lines. please excuse me if there is some wrong in that

Comment: @MasoudHabibi: Profile it with `callgrind`. Analyze the output with `kcachegrind`. Figure out what's performing badly.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I said I just measured time around .add and .push_back. so other things has no important

Comment: @MasoudHabibi: CPU time? Wall clock time? Using what functions? (It's surprisingly easy to measure time incorrectly. You may just be measuring the time of your time measuring code!)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : at first of measurement I put mCounter++; int t1 = clock(); and at the end of it int t2 = clock(); mtime += t2 - t2; if (mCounter > 10000) { cout << mTime * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << '\n';}

Comment: @Mankarse by showing how a proper measurement would be done (at least to backup the claims by the OP) you could show the OP what he does /wrong/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your 'equivalent' code.

1) C++ has to deallocate the `vector` at the end of the block. C# can just keep on rolling and deletes the objects and lists at the end of the programs lifetime

2) C++ string and C# string are completely different things. The `std::string` in C++ is a array of chars  which can store arbitrary length stings and has to allocate/deallocate memory. the C# `string` is a pointer which is most likely `null`.

Comment: I posted the real code. as you can see there is no deallocation

Answer (score 4):

The biggest difference will be that the C++ code destroys the local `vector` after each loop iteration, freeing the memory that was allocated by `push_back`. The C# code just abandons its reference to the local `List`, leaving the garbage collector to deal with it. This is likely to make that loop faster, although the total amount of work done by the program will probably be very similar.

There are probably many other differences; you're comparing two different languages with different performance characteristics.

Comment: It seems I am really awful at summarizing my code. It is really recursive. Not a simple for.

Comment: There's no point in analyzing the performance of fake code. Analyze the performance of your real code and optimize it, if necessary.

Comment: As I said there is no local vector. and there is no freeing memory. I just get time of .add and .push_back

Answer (score 3):

C++ is value-based, i.e., you create copies of the `m1` objects. C# is referenced based, i.e., you store references to the object.

That said, I think the performance test you created doesn't really measure anything! I can imagine that either compiler can detect that nothing is really done inside the loop and optimize it away. A more reasonable test would be adding elements to a container passed by reference (C# passes pointers by default, that'll do) to a function.

Comment: Yeah. Microbenchmarking is both hard and frequently useless. I was gonna say this, but I was out of energy for the rest of the responses for the moment :) (FWIW, C# has `struct` valuetypes which make the outer type be copied like in C++ value semantics. Not the string itself, though)

Comment: I corrected the code and posted the real code. There is nothing to be omitted by compiler. And there is nothing about value-base against reference base

Comment: Hm. Performance analysis tends to depend on what exactly you are doing when trying to pin-point where the issue is. With the changed code I would probably blame the memory allocation strategy and see what happens when using a pool allocator in C++ (the brute force version being to replace the memory allocation operators to `malloc()` lots of memory and just hand out the next piece, delete doing nothing). One suspicion could that the C++ allocator could cope with multiple threads.